C static local variable, volatile required or not if function called from different non-concurrent ISRs?
I have a private function that does operations on a static local variable. This function is called from different non-concurrent hardware ISRs. Instinctively, I would believe this to be correct since the variable is static and its value must persist across function calls, but I'd like to be 100% certain. I am not too confident about what the compiler does and if the resulting instructions would contain optimization which would result in incorrect read values (like when a non-volatile global is read from a background loop but modified in an ISR).
/** @brief Raise the event flag and feed the watchdog if all required event flags are set.
 *
 *  @param[in] event_flag  Bitmask corresponding to the triggering event.
 */
static void watchdog_feed_if_all_events_set(watchdog_event_t event_flag)
{
    static watchdog_event_t watchdog_feed_events;

    watchdog_feed_events |= event_flag;

    if ((watchdog_feed_events & watchdog_required_events) == watchdog_required_events) {
        bsp_watchdog_feed();
        watchdog_feed_events = 0;
    }
}

Does watchdog_feed_events need to be declared as volatile? If so, could you explain why?

Are the ISR concurrent or not? Usually one interrupt inhibit others. But reading probably is concurrent? In such case, check how to handle concurrent programming in C (volatile will not help much, if structure is not atomic, and so probably you need a lock).

Hi, thanks for you comment. The ISRs are not concurrent, I edited the question to clarify.

"non-concurrent hardware ISRs." --> really?  HW ISR usually do not both prevent the other.  One usually  has higher priority.

I am not sure what the background of your question is. Please explain your understanding of the relation of volatile, reentrancy, concurrency, the need for synchronisation. I ask because answers (though bad answers) could be "yes" or "no". Even with explanation I worry that you take the wrong understanding away. You wisely ask because you are NOT sure about your understanding, I recommend to still explain it so that on top of giving you the answer you ask for you might get (though not necessarily from me) the answer you need.

@chux IMO the question is if this value will be not optimized in register

@chux Equal priorities hardware IRQs will not prempt each other.

@Yunnosch That is a good idea, let me update the question accordingly. In short, I am concerned about compiler optimization.

The elephant in the room is that you should never ever feed the watch dog from within an ISR in the first place. So what you are doing seems senseless and you should seriously reconsider the program design.

This is my first time with watchdogs. Why is it senseless? Would you have any specific resources detailing best practices with watchdogs? As you can see, the watchdog only gets fed if all event flags are set. In other words, if one ISR gets stuck or stops working, the watchdog will trigger. What's wrong with this?


Does watchdog_feed_events need to be declared as volatile? If so,
could you explain why?

It does not have to be volatile if the function makes only one change:

it has a static storage duration and must be read when the function is called from its permanent storage duration. Even if this function is inlined in the ISR handler, the compiler cannot optimize it and keep it in register between the ISR handler vectoring.

If the function can change it many times and can be preempted, then it should be volatile. But in this case the complex operations will have to be placed in the critical sections.
The volatile only informs the compiler that the object is side effects prone and it has to be read from its permanent storage before every read and saved after every modification.

When you say "if the function makes only one change", I am assuming you mean an atomic operation? Otherwise, what I'm getting from your answer is that a static variable will always be re-read from its storage location upon function entry. I'm not too well versed in assembly but this seems to be enough to not require a volatile declaration in this context.

@DarkFranX I meant if it so simple as yours

Look a this example: https://godbolt.org/z/1TYco6xM1
The compiler will store the variable, if volatile, after each modify and read it back again.
If your ISRs are non-concurrent, then you can get away with not making it volatile, since code would not get preempted. The access will be basically atomic.
That said, I would say, if you work not alone on this project, make it volatile.
The speed impact will be small, as well as the memory footprint. And most important, if the variable will, at some point, be used at other places as well, you will not have have less issues with concurrent access.
